# Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, browser-link

### Background:

Using `Visual Studio 2015`, `ASP.NET Core 1.0` I have created `Web Application` project. When I run application and go to `Chrome Console` I have following error:

> Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null

### Question:

How to fix above error and make `Browser Link` working?

Comment: Could you possibly include some code in your question, please? It is hard to help you if you haven't included some code

Comment: Weeeeellll, that all depends on the code that's throwing the error. Could you add the offending code to your question?

Comment: It is the default project, I did not make any amends to it. Project did have a lot of files included, it is hard for me to find out which is causing a problem.

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in Visual Studio `Browser Link` functionality.

Comment: The error in the console ought to tell you where the bug is coming from. Click on the file link to the right of the error message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624173/jquery-getjson-error-browser-link-failed-to-invoke-return-value-callback-ty

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio right of the play button should be button with an arrow going around in a circle.  Under here are some options for Browser Link, you can try "Refresh Linked Browsers", and if that doesn't work there is a tick box to turn it off "Enable Browser Link"

This link might also be useful: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It went away when i did a `repair` on `Visual Studio`