# jQuery.getJSON() error: Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-visualization

I'm following @Sam Farajpour Ghamari 's answer from: [How to populate google charts using data from database created via code first - ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524745/how-to-populate-google-charts-using-data-from-database-created-via-code-first)

**That is my script.js**

```
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'line'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);
function drawLineColors() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('number', '@Model.Days');
    data.addColumn('number', '@Model.Time');

    console.log("!!!");
    //data.addRows([       
    //    [9, 12], [11, 14]
    //]);

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:4411/GetChart", null, function (chartData) {
        $.each(chartData, function (i, item) {
                data.addRows([[item.Days, item.Time]]);
        );


        var options = {
            title: 'You can see on chart in which time you eat',
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Days'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Time'
            },
            colors: ['#FF6B00', '#0033FF']
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

As you can see i put "http://localhost:4411/GetChart" instead of "@Url.Action('GetChart')" because first one did not work.

**And in controller i have:**

```
[Route("/GetChart")]
        public IActionResult GetChart()
        {
            return Json(_db.database
                .Select(p =>new {p.Days, p.Time}));
        }
```

**http://localhost:4411/GetChart in the browser returns:**

```
[{"Days":1101,"Time":20},{"Days":1102,"Time":20},{"Days":1103,"Time":20}]
```

Commented hard-coded version "[9, 12], [11, 14]" worked okay, but current script.js version returns errors in browser console(F12):

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3 
!!!
browserLink:64 [00:57:43 GMT+0400 (Russian Daylight Time)] Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null
```

As a result I have empty diagram without data. I need help to understand where do i have problem? Maybe the problem is that script is looking for data in the format of: [[days],[time]] , but instead it gets it in the format: [{data},{time}]  If it so, how can i fix it?
Let me know if any additional information is needed. Thanks for your time and answers.

Comment: So you need this version of jquery in your code: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/1.9.1.

Comment: I have downloaded version 1.9.1 at NuGet package manager, but problem still exists. @applecrusher , do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Is there a html file to put the jquery code or a way to import the script?

Comment: What do you mean? My jquery code is above. Sorry, i don't understand you, @applecrusher . I'm using Visual Studio

Comment: Is there a page with html anywhere that is using this script?

Comment: Yes. A view page chart.cshtml that only calls the script.js                      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/script.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. Really stupid mistake. I just had to change this:

```
data.addRows([[item.Days, item.Time]]);
```

to this:

```
data.addRows([[item.days, item.time]]);
```

Now I would like to understand why is it so? In my project I have named Days and Time using Capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

"Now I would like to understand why is it so? In my project I have named Days and Time using Capital letter."

Are you using asp.net Core? if yes, you have to turn of the camelCase convenction thats ON by default.